# Remove latex command with sed

Tags: remove

I need to remove index entries from a section in a latex file, e.g.:
`\index[lugares]{London}`
or
`\index[lugares]{London|see{Londinium}}`
I have tried this:
`sed 's/\index[^)]*}//g' apendice.txt > apendice2.txt`

But it left the first backslash and longer entries such as this:
`\index[lugares]{Oropesa (Oropesa del Mar)}`

Comment: I would rather use something like `\\index\[.*?\]{.*?}`, since you need to escape the first backslash when using regex.

Comment: No. This ```sed 's/\\index\[.*?\]{.*?}//g' apendice.txt > apendice2.txt``` leaves all as it was.

Comment: You could nullify `\index[.]{..}` from within LaTeX itself rather than removing the commands explicitly.

Comment: Still I will need to replace one by one, right? The bad thing about removing one by one or changing is that every time you modify a text you leave errors behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Werner suggested in the comments, you can store the definition of the `\index` macro, temporarily redefine it to do nothing and restore it later, like in the following code. You would then not need to delete the macro from the code using `sed`.

(Similarly, you can redefine the macros that deactivate and reactivate the `\index` macro themselves.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex[name=lugares]

\newcommand{\ignoreindexon}{%
    \let\oldIndex\index%
    \renewcommand{\index}[2][]{}%
}

\newcommand{\ignoreindexoff}{
    \renewcommand{\index}[2][]{\oldIndex[##1]{##2}}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \index[lugares]{London}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \ignoreindexon
    \index[lugares]{London|see{Londinium}}
    \ignoreindexoff
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \index[lugares]{Oropesa (Oropesa del Mar)}
    
    \printindex[lugares]
    
\end{document}
```

Output of the index:

[image]